# an elegant way to matching a route

Tags: php, regex, refactoring

im stuck on a piece of code which is looking terrible.

i got an route as string like `/people/12/edit` and i want to compare it with routes in my dataset.
in the dataset there are routes like:

- /people
- /people/:id
- /people/new
- /people/:id/edit

i need to know, that my route `/people/12/edit` goes to the internal action for `/people/:id/edit`

so i had the following condition to check this:

```
if(preg_match("/^".preg_replace('/:id/','([0-9]*)?',preg_replace('/\//','\/',$_route['route']))."$/", $route)){
    // ...
}
```

but it seems to be a bad solution. i have to escape the slashes, i have to replace the :id parameter, and after this, i can check if the route is matching.

but it looks terrible and has a big problem. it doenst work if the parameter is not named `:id`.

can you give me some hint or show a better way?

thanks in advance

update:
im not using any mvc framework. its an "build your own framework and learn task"

the routes stored on a route table:

```
people_index        get     /people         people#index
people_show     get     /people/:id         people#show
people_edit     get     /people/:id/edit            people#edit
people_update       put     /people/:id         people#update
people_new      get     /people/new         people#new
people_create       post        /people         people#create
people_delete       delete      /people/:id         people#delete
```

if i call `link_to 'people_index'` it will display `/people`. the condition above is part of the routing parser. it just looking for the correct uri and return (for the edit link) `people#edit`. after this, i know there is an resource `PeoplesController` and call the `edit` action.

i know there are lots of great mvc frameworks for php. but i want to get more experience and rebuild some rails logic into php :)

Comment: Are you using any frameworks (MVC, etc.) or  tools to help with routing? Also: you want to ensure that your URL's are being mapped properly? I think more information surrounding what you are trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: what you need is this in place of :id  ([0-9]+|new) how you get that is up to you.  this ([0-9]*)? says that 0 or more numbers 0-9 are optional. which having 0 or more already implies.  so you could have // as valid path and nothing for new.  Hard to tell with the way it is written.

Comment: as another note using the route as part of the expression, i would suggest using preg_quote, because query parameters will kill you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all I would split this up some, preferable in a reusable way, say a function to parse the mapping first.

```
function createpattern( $map ) {
       $map = preg_replace('/:id/', '([0-9]+|new)', $map );
       //add other mappings here for example.
       $map = preg_replace('/:name/', '([a-z])', $map );
      return $map;
}
```

Or just use rusty trusty str_replace for this part.

```
function createpattern( $map ) {
      $search = array( ':id', ':name' );
      $replace = array( '([0-9]+|new)', '([a-z]+)?');
      $map = preg_quote($map); //maybe use it here.

      $map = str_replace($search,   $replace, $map );
      return $map;
}
```

So this

```
 /people/:id
```

becomes

```
 /people/([0-9]+|new)
```

Somewhere you should use preg_quote, but not after adding in the regx bits.

essentially your regx is now

```
 \/people\/([0-9]+|new)\/... etc.
```

preg_quote would be used to prevent a user from adding in regular expressions of there own and messing up yours, unintentional and otherwise.

Comment: thats a great solution and looks quite better. really helpfull! thank you very much